# How to remove this SQL clause duplication?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, duplicates, query-optimization

I have 2 queries which do SELECT with the same condition on the same table. Could you please help me to remove this duplication?

```
if exists(select count(1)    
              from (<table>) t   
              where  (<condition>)   
              having count(1) = 1)   
    set @yes = 1    

if @yes = 1    
    select @x = X   
        from (<table>) t   
        where  (<condition>)
```

Comment: can you add sample records with desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check whether u mean this:

```
    select 
      @x = X   
    from 
      (<table>) t   
    where  
      (<condition>)
    group by X
    having count(*) = 1
```

OR

```
select 
    @x = X  
from(
    select 
        count(*) over() cnt, X    
    from 
        (<table>) t  
    where  
        (<condition>)
)a
WHERE a.cnt=1
```

Comment: If I understand the question right, this fails when multiple rows with *different* `X` qualify according to <condition>.

Comment: Did you add GROUP BY because of "Column 'X' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I guess even SKINDER's sample query will also have the same issue. SKINDER - Yes

Comment: @techdo: No, it doesn't. `@yes` is only 1 in the example, if there is exactly one row matching <condition>.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is equivalent to:

```
select @yes = 1,@x=max(X) from (<table>) t   
       where  (<condition>)   
       having count(1) = 1
```

Comment: @x should be null if we have 0 or 2 rows with required <condition>

Comment: It WILL be NULL in this case (as soon @yes will be NULL too). Try to run this query.

Answer (score 1):

`EXISTS` can serve as just another `WHERE` condition:

```
SELECT @x = X
FROM   <table> t
WHERE  <condition>
AND    EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM   <table> t1
    WHERE  <condition>
    HAVING count(*) = 1
    );
```

Basically it selects `X` from `<table>` only if there is *only row qualifying*.
Or (may be faster):

```
SELECT @x = X
FROM  <table> t
WHERE <condition>
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM   <table> t1
    WHERE  <condition>
    AND    t1.id <> t.id     -- no other row satisfies same conditions
    );
```

`id` being the primary key or `<table>`.
The reverse logic: only select the qualifying row, if *no other row qualifies*.

Comment: And yes, it is the same table.

Answer (score 0):

if 'X' field in your table not null you can use this query:

```
SET @x = null

SELECT @x = X   
        FROM (<table>) t   
        WHERE (<condition>)
IF (@x IS NOT NULL) BEGIN SET @yes = 1 END
```

Comment: I need to get X if <table> contains only 1 row with required <condition>